# How to use alphabetical order in ng-options using Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm working on Angularjs and I need to set my drop down list in  alphabetical order.

Here is the ng-option:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Branch : <i class="mandate">*</i></label>
  <select class="form-control input-md" ng-model="query.branch" ng-options="showName(branch.branchName) as   showName(branch.branchName) for branch in baseBranches | orderBy:'toString()'" name="branchName">
    <option value="" selected>Select Branch</option>
  </select>
  <span class="error" ng-show="search_form.branchName.$error.required">Branch is required</span>
</div>
```

I'm new to Angularjs.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310782/sorting-dropdown-alphabetically-in-angularjs

Comment: @Sa E Chowdary tried it but not working, because i'm  using the function showname to  remove the numbers and spaces in  my  drop down data.

Comment: well,we cant guess what your doing with your function calls right.....so answered according to the data provided by you.as the accepted answe in that you need to pass key to the order by

Comment: if you provide your data in $scope.baseBranches  then we can give you the ecpected output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Order by filter in angular js.

```
<select class="form-control input-md" 
        ng-model="query.branch" 
        ng-options="showName(branch.branchName) as   showName(branch.branchName) for branch in baseBranches | orderBy:'branchName'" name="branchName">
    <option value="" selected>Select Branch</option>
</select>
```

If you are sure that your option format is something like this `[number][space][word]` or you need to sort depend up on the word after space, you can write a custom filter for that. I have attached a sample code snippet with a **custom filter** here with.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="item.Name for item in names | customSorter:'Name'">
        </select>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.names = [{
                    "Id": 0,
                    "Name": "10095 Gil"
            }, {
                    "Id": 1,
                    "Name": "00085 Tobias"
            },
                {
                    "Id": 2,
                    "Name": "145 Linus"
            }];
        });
        app.filter('customSorter', function () {
            return function (items, field) {
                var filtered = [];
                angular.forEach(items, function (item) {
                    filtered.push(item);
                });
                filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
                    return (a.Name.split(' ')[1] > b.Name.split(' ')[1]);
                });

                return filtered;

            };
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have added a custom filter which sorts the array depending on the word after space and order the `ng option` depending on that.
You can find the details of `ng-options` [here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)

Comment: @ Nitheesh its correct  but my  json  data is in  this format  :  "branchName": "0082 MAHESANA",

Comment: @ Nitheesh i  was used a function  showname to remove the numbers and spaces in my drop down data. And the requirement is to  show it in  Alphabetical  order.

Comment: Then try using orderBy: showName(branch.branchName). Im not sure about the result in this case. Please check that.

Comment: @ChethanaC Are you sure that the name will comes in a unique format say [number][space][word] ?

Answer (score 3):

ng-repeat is working for me , check the [pen](http://codepen.io/mgp/pen/eBxqqg)

```
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Branch : <i class="mandate">*</i></label>
       <select >
         <option value="" selected>Select Branch</option>
         <option ng-repeat=" item in main.items | orderBy:'toString()'" value="      {{item}}">{{item}}</option>
       </select>

     </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Branch : <i class="mandate">*</i></label>
  <select class="form-control input-md" ng-model="query.branch" ng-options="showName(branch.branchName) as   showName(branch.branchName) for branch in baseBranches | orderBy:'branchName'">
    <option value="" selected>Select Branch</option>
  </select>
  <span class="error" ng-show="search_form.branchName.$error.required">Branch is required</span>
</div>
```