# Angular Order Values in ng-options

Tags: angularjs

I have the following Object which contains Objets in itself:

```
var myObj = {
    1:{ 
        id:1,
        name:'John',
        otherVal='LoremIpsum'
    },
    2:{
        id:2,
        name:'Bill',
        otherVal='LoremIpsum'
    },
    3:{
        id: 3,
        name:'Steve',
        otherVal='LoremIpsum'
    }};
```

I show the values of `name` inside these object in an select field in the following way:

```
<select name="someName" ng-model="someModel"
        ng-options="person.id as person.name for person in myObj"
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

How can I sort the `<option>`'s alphabetically by the value `name`?

Comment: What is myObj? An Object or an Array? According to your code it is an Object. But it should be an Array.

Comment: It is an Object. Why should it be an Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple.

Just update your code with the below one.

```
   <select name="someName" ng-model="someModel"
           ng-options="person.id as person.name for person in myObj | orderBy:'name'"
           <option value=""></option>
   </select>
```

**OR**

Go to: [Sorting dropdown alphabetically in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310782/sorting-dropdown-alphabetically-in-angularjs)